# Find/replace arbitrary JS properties for better compression

Tags: javascript, shell, batch-file, replace, minify

I could effectively reduce the size of some of our JS production code if I could granularly minify those properties that I know to be arbitrary, but which don't get minified on standard settings. That is, replace them with a single character like 'a' in the way that minification does, when advanced minification settings are too problematic. A text file could be maintained as part of the project with a comma separated list of known replacable strings.

Does anybody have a bat or shell script that can achieve this, even manually per-file from a csv? Or another suggestion for achieving the same thing? I'm on windows so a sh script would need to work in Git bash, for me anyway :)

As well as the find/replace aspect, the replacement strings would need to be generated so as to be unique but as short as possible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Git bash. Does it include sed? Search and replace is trivial with sed (e.g., `sed -i -e 's:needle:replacement:g' <file>`). I believe you could throw a whole file list at that as well, not just a single file, otherwise a simple shell script could loop them.

Comment: Yes sed is in there. I've edited my question to highlight the other aspect to the process.

Comment: This would be fairly simple to write in C++, Java, Python, etc.  Got a favorite?  It could also be done easily in JavaScript, but you'd have mouse clicks to open the strings file and the code.

Comment: How would you suggest writing to the file system in JavaScript? I once did it with the .hta extension, some years ago.

Comment: You can either just use textarea controls as most minifiers do, or, you could use a browse control to read the file and a download link when the file is written.  I am working on a JSFiddle for this right now with textarea controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a C++ version for those who do not want to use JavaScript.  It uses only the standard C++ libraries.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <vector>
#include <string>

void Usage(const char* msg = NULL)
{
    if (msg)
        printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf("Usage: coderep (prefix) (infile) (listfile) (outfile)\n");
}

char* OpenAndReadFile(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fp)
        return NULL;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = (int)ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* buf = new char[size + 2];
    fread(buf, 1, size, fp);
    buf[size] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);
    return buf;
}

void ReplaceAll(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to)
{
    size_t start_pos = 0;
    while ((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
        start_pos += to.length();
    }
}

char* rndCh = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
int rndLen = 62;

// Generate random string from number
void genRand(int index, std::string* str)
{
    std::vector<int> ni;
    while (index > 0)
    {
        ni.push_back(index % 62);
        index = index / 62;
    }
    if (!ni.size())
        ni.push_back(0);

    std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator ip;
    for (ip = ni.rbegin();  ip != ni.rend();  ++ip)
        (*str) += rndCh[*ip];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 5)
    {
        Usage();
        return 1;
    }

    // Read inputs and check parms
    const char* prefix = argv[1];
    char* code = OpenAndReadFile(argv[2]);
    if (!code || !*code)
    {
        Usage("Failed reading code");
        return 1;
    }
    char* list = OpenAndReadFile(argv[3]);
    if (!list || !*list)
    {
        delete[] code;
        Usage("Failed reading list");
        return 1;
    }
    const char* outfile = argv[4];
    if (!outfile || !*outfile)
    {
        Usage("Need output file");
        return 1;
    }

    // Split list
    std::string scode(code);
    std::vector<std::string> vlist;
    std::string acc;
    const char* lp = list;
    while (*lp)
    {
        if (*lp == L',')
        {
            vlist.push_back(acc);
            acc.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            acc += *lp;
        }
        ++lp;
    }
    if (acc.size() > 0)
        vlist.push_back(acc);

    // Do translation
    int index = 0;
    std::string rstr;
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator ilist;
    for (ilist = vlist.begin();  ilist != vlist.end();  ++ilist)
    {
        rstr = prefix;
        genRand(index, &rstr);
        ++index;

        ReplaceAll(scode, *ilist, rstr);
    }

    // Write results
    FILE* outp = fopen(outfile, "wb");
    if (!outp)
    {
        Usage("Error creating output file");
        return 1;
    }
    fwrite(scode.c_str(), sizeof(char), scode.size(), outp);
    fclose(outp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works great, thanks! What was your thinking with the prefix, not sure I see the need for one? I see that this version allows empty quotes though.

Comment: It was to gain some control over the randomly generated names.  Feel free to not use it, of course.

Comment: I think I see a problem with not using a prefix - a property name can't start with a number. They aren't actually random though, rather index based? If so the first loop could be %52?

Comment: Sure, you can put any characters you want in the array to not use numbers at all.  Just remove 0-9 and change rndLen to 52.

Comment: Thanks again for coding this up, really awesome.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've posted a bare bones JavaScript / HTML solution in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh5xU/11/).  Here is the JavaScript code without the HTML and CSS which are in the fiddle:

```
rndCh = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
rndLen = rndCh.length;

// Generate random string from number
function genRand(index) {
    var ni = [], rv = "";
    while (index > 0) {
        ni.push(index % 62);
        index = ~~(index / 62);
    }
    if (!ni.length) {
        ni.push(0);
    }
    while (ni.length > 0) {
        rv += rndCh[ni.pop()];
    }
    return rv;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gobutton").on("click", function(e) {
        var prefix, code, rlist, ir, nrep, nrval;

        prefix = $("#myprefix").val();
        if (!prefix) {
            alert("Need prefix");
            return;
        }
        code = $("#mycode").val();
        if (!code) {
            alert("Need code");
            return;
        }
        rlist = $("#mylist").val();
        if (!rlist || !rlist.length) {
            alert("Need replacement list");
            return;
        }
        rlist = rlist.split(",");

        for (ir = 0;  ir < rlist.length;  ++ir) {
            if (rlist[ir]) {
                // Generate next random
                nrval = prefix + genRand(ir);
                nrep = new RegExp(rlist[ir], "g");
                code = code.replace(nrep, nrval);
            }
        }

        $("#myoutput").val(code);
    });
});
```

Comment: Love that genRand, thanks would have taken me a long while to boil it down that well. Overall though, a web interface feels a bit too manual for regular deploys?

Comment: Well, you asked above about JavaScript.  I could just as easily translate this to other OS indy languages like C++ if you like.

Comment: Ah, apologies I interpreted your original question as rhetorical :) I usually run minification apps like Google closure compiler & YUI compressor from windows cmd, they are java utils. If the params included input file(s) and csv file, that would indeed be ideal :) I think this idea actually has legs, i'm suprised not to find any mention of it in my searches.

Comment: OK, I have posted a separate answer with a C++ version.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said sed was available, I've tested a solution in sed, and the following should do the trick:

```
sed -i -e 's:\bfirstNeedle\b:firstReplacement:g' -e 's:\bsecondNeedle\b:secondReplacement:g' [... and so on...] /path/to/first/file /path/to/second/file [etc...]
```

The `-i` flag means edit in place (so it overwrites the original file provided (I'd make a backup of your folders before-hand of course). Each replacement is easily provided using the `-e` flag (expression). The replacement itself is `s` to signify replacement, followed by a separator character, a regular expression that matches what you want to replace, another separator, then the replacement you want to use; this can use groupings from the regex as well, so you can do the following (or any other such tricks):

```
sed -i -e 's:\bget(([A-Z]{1,3})[a-zA-Z]*\(\)):g\1:g'
```

Which would match getters and replace them with g[first-1-to-3-letters-of-next-word], shortening them easily. Of course, this does not guarantee uniqueness, you'd have to make sure of that yourself.

If you have a lot of replacements to do, you can create the expressions by placing them as pairs in a file `original=replacement` (one per line), then use `echo $(sed -e "s:([^=]*)=(.*):-e\ 's=\b\1\b\2=g':" /path/to/replacements/file)` to print out the list of replacements. (Here I'm using `=` as the separator char just to make the replacement file easier to understand and possibly re-use, feel free to use whatever separator character you want).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the breakdown. The unique replacements needs to be delivered by the program though so as not to become a front-end constraint? Perhaps a utility like the C++ answer is more suited to the logic required?

Comment: @robC I'd say it depends a little on how much and what you're replacing. I wouldn't recommend the second example unless you know that all your getters have the first {x} characters as a unique combination, it was just an example of what you could do. If you maintain a list yourself however it's easy enough as you're mapping from one specific string to another. As long as all the strings on the right side of the equals are unique you'll be fine. Btw. it's occurred to me that it should be looking for word boundaries, so I've added that (note the `\b`s).